# Why Camera activity returning null?

Tags: android, xamarin

I used below codes for taking image from camera and put it in Image View (imgViewAds).

```
private void BtnPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(builder.Build());


    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    var activities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(cameraIntent, 0);
    if (activities.Count > 0)
    {
        addAds.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        Java.IO.File imageFile = new Java.IO.File(AdsAdapter.ImagePath(addAds.ImageName));
        Android.Net.Uri imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(imageFile);
        cameraIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraSizeLimit, 1024*10);
        cameraIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);


        StartActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);

    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Not Camera", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

And here is OnActivityResult the the camare send result here.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{

    if (resultCode == Result.Ok && (data != null))
    {
        Bundle extras = data.Extras;
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.Get("data");
        imgViewAds.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        imageBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
        addAds.AdsImage = stream.ToArray();
    }
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

but the data that sending to OnActivityResult is null and Image did not come to Image View.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` with a URI to write to, the camera intent will be `null` and the picture is in the URI that you passed in.

so you could simply remove these two lines:

```
Android.Net.Uri imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(imageFile);
cameraIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);
```

note that in this way you get the thumbnail of the image. so if you want the whole image you could use something like this (I haven't tested the code, but you could get the idea):

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            addAds.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        Java.IO.File imageFile = new Java.IO.File(AdsAdapter.ImagePath(addAds.ImageName));
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                bitmap = cropAndScale(bitmap, 300); // if you mind scaling
                profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```